# Standard deviation map shows pixels as null in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, layers, maps, reducers

I need some help in understanding image reducing with kernels.
I have a code that generates a band of NDVI stdDev 3X3 kernel. When I map the layer the outcome is an image with empty pixels with a colored frame. Why is that? Why isn't the whole pixel colored?
When I inspect the pixel I get a value of 0 but when I zoom out and inspect the pixel I get a numbered value. Why isn't every pixel colored and with a value like a regular NDVI image?

```
/-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Set up basic variables (NDVI).
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var shpfile_name     = 'Tzora_Field_10_4_polygons_3857_Buffer-2'; // Shapefile name (from Assets).
var folder           = ''
var image_collection = "COPERNICUS/S2_SR"//image collection.
var first_date       = '2021-04-16' // First date in image collection
var last_date        = '2021-12-29' // Last date in image collection
var user_account     = 'users/yonatangoldwasser/'
var fc_ID            = 'Group'; // Field name of column with plot names.
var min_v            = 0.05
var max_v            = 0.75
var Name             = 'Corn Field 10-4 Tzora'
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Load raster data (COPERNICUS/S2_SR).
// Load vector data (shapefile).
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(user_account+folder+shpfile_name).sort('Group');
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection(image_collection)
        .filterDate(first_date, last_date)
        .filterBounds(fc)
        .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 18);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print(S2)
print(fc)           // CRS must be WGS84 (for the shapefile)          

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Image Expression for calculating NDVI----------------------------------------------
var band_1 = 'B4'
var band_2 = 'B8'

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var NDVI = image.expression(
  '(B8-B4)/(B8+B4)',
  {
    'B4': image.select('B4'),
    'B8': image.select('B8'),

  }).rename('NDVI');
  //NDVI index
  return image.addBands(NDVI.add(ee.Image(0.0)));
  //Add 0.0 value to NDVI (currently not in use)
};

// Calculate NDVIfor images in the Image collection 
var S2_withNDVI = ee.ImageCollection(S2).map(addNDVI);          
print(S2_withNDVI) 
// Compute 3X3 standard deviation kernel (SD) as texture of the NDVI.
var addTexture_3X3_stdDev = function(image) {
var texture = image.select('NDVI').reduceNeighborhood({
reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev().unweighted(),
kernel: ee.Kernel.square(1),
}).rename('NDVI_3X3_stdDev')
return image.addBands(texture.add(ee.Image(0.0)));
};
var S2_Analysis = ee.ImageCollection(S2_Analysis).map(addTexture_3X3_stdDev);
print(S2_Analysis)
// Show images of NDVI (over image collection) on GEE. 
var count = S2_Analysis.size(); 
print ('size of collection imageSet', count);
var imageSetCollection = S2_Analysis.toList(count)
print(imageSetCollection)
var ID = imageSetCollection.id

ee.List.sequence(0,ee.Number(count.subtract(1))).getInfo()
.map(function(img){


  var image = ee.Image(imageSetCollection.get(img))
Map.addLayer(image.select("NDVI_3X3_stdDev"), {min: 0, max: 0.006, palette: palette})
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your example, Earth Engine didn't find your assets, but maybe your problem is related to this other question:
[Statistics of Image Neighborhood in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266825/statistics-of-image-neighborhood-in-google-earth-engine)

The fact is that earth engine computes kernel reductions according to zoom level. In your case, it will compute in a 3x3 pixel square, but as far as I know, when EE is doing this it actually doesn't know what is an image pixel, it uses the pixels from your screen computer (or something related).

What I do to overcome that is to set the scale unit in the kernel to meters and then use a multiple of the pixel resolution from the data (which we usually know). Your kernel would look something like this: `ee.Kernel.square(30,'meters')`

But maybe I got wrong your point. Let me know if I'm helping in some way.